# Getting 500 error with Laravel 5.2 CORS POST

Tags: laravel

I tried to use laravel-cors (https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors) with Laravel 5.2 to update data, but I always get the same error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dev.pesanlab.com/api/v1/order/cart/add. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

GET request works fine, but POST return error.

```
return [
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE'],
    'exposedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'maxAge' => 0,
    'hosts' => [],
];
```

This is my code on `Route.php`

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1'], function () {
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'cors']], function () {
        Route::post('order/cart/add','OrderController@cart_add');
    });
});
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Can you share some code with us?

Comment: Remove the `web` middleware and try again and let's see if that works or not.

Comment: still error with same message

Comment: Add this `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");` in your `public.index.php` and check if it works for now.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is not the request but the error that is giving. The error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load   http://dev.pesanlab.com/api/v1/order/cart/add. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
```

have at the end the status code 500 (Internal server error). Start with the debugging and try to locate the real error:

Enable debug in Laravel:

config/app.php:

```
'debug' => env('APP_DEBUG', true),
```

Or use the default php show errors:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Or check the laravel.log

```
Storage/logs/laravel.log
```

After you manage to do this you can see the original error: